# TiledLayer equivalent in Android

Tags: android, tiles

To draw landscapes, backgrounds with patterns etc, we used TiledLayer in J2ME. Is there an android counterpart for that. Does android provide an option to set such tiled patterns in the layout XML?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this class as a equivalent "TiledLayer class of jme":

```
package net.obviam.walking;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.kilobolt.framework.Graphics;
import com.kilobolt.framework.Image;
import com.kilobolt.framework.implementation.AndroidImage;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;

public class TiledLayer {

    public static final int DIR_LEFT = 0;
    public static final int DIR_RIGHT = 1;
    public static final int DIR_UP = 2;
    public static final int DIR_DOWN = 3;

    private int cellWidth;
    private int cellHeight;
    private int yPosition = 0, xPosition = 0;
    private int[][] grid;
    private Image image;
    private Bitmap tileArray[];
    private int[] tileXPositions;
    private int[] tileYPositions;
    private ArrayList animatedTiles;
    private int numberOfTiles;
    private int numberOfColumns;
    private int numberOfRows;
    private int gridColumns;
    private int gridRows, width, height;
    int tileCounter;

    public TiledLayer(Image image, int columns, int rows, int tileWidth,
            int tileHeight, int width, int height) {
        this.grid = new int[columns][rows];
        this.gridColumns = columns;
        this.gridRows = rows;
        this.width = columns * tileWidth;
        this.height = rows * tileHeight;
        this.animatedTiles = new ArrayList();
        this.cellWidth = tileWidth;
        this.cellHeight = tileHeight;
        int r = image.getHeight() / tileHeight;
        int c = image.getWidth() / tileWidth;
        tileArray = new Bitmap[(r * c) + 1];
        setStaticTileSet(image, tileWidth, tileHeight);
    }

    public TiledLayer(Bitmap image, int columns, int rows, int tileWidth,
            int tileHeight, int width, int height) {
        this.grid = new int[columns][rows];
        this.gridColumns = columns;
        this.gridRows = rows;
        this.width = columns * tileWidth;
        this.height = rows * tileHeight;
        this.animatedTiles = new ArrayList();
        this.cellWidth = tileWidth;
        this.cellHeight = tileHeight;
        int r = image.getHeight() / tileHeight;
        int c = image.getWidth() / tileWidth;
        tileArray = new Bitmap[(r * c) + 1];
        setStaticTileSet(image, tileWidth, tileHeight);
    }

    public void setStaticTileSet(Image image, int tileWidth, int tileHeight) {
        tileArray[0] = Bitmap.createBitmap(tileWidth, tileHeight,
                Config.ARGB_4444);
        int rows = image.getHeight() / tileHeight;
        int columns = image.getWidth() / tileWidth;
        numberOfTiles = rows * columns;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            yPosition = i * tileHeight;
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                xPosition = j * tileWidth;
                tileCounter++;
                tileArray[tileCounter] = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                        ((AndroidImage) image).bitmap, xPosition, yPosition,
                        tileWidth, tileHeight);
            }
        }
        if (gridColumns * gridRows < this.numberOfTiles) {
            // clear the grid, when there are not as many tiles as in the
            // previous set:
            for (int i = 0; i < this.grid.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < this.grid[i].length; j++) {
                    this.grid[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void setStaticTileSet(Bitmap image, int tileWidth, int tileHeight) {
        tileArray[0] = Bitmap.createBitmap(tileWidth, tileHeight,
                Config.ARGB_4444);
        int rows = image.getHeight() / tileHeight;
        int columns = image.getWidth() / tileWidth;
        numberOfTiles = rows * columns;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            yPosition = i * tileHeight;
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                xPosition = j * tileWidth;
                tileCounter++;
                tileArray[tileCounter] = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, xPosition,
                        yPosition, tileWidth, tileHeight);
            }
        }

        if (gridColumns * gridRows < this.numberOfTiles) {
            // clear the grid, when there are not as many tiles as in the
            // previous set:
            for (int i = 0; i < this.grid.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < this.grid[i].length; j++) {
                    this.grid[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int createAnimatedTile(int staticTileIndex) {
        if (staticTileIndex >= this.numberOfTiles) {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid static tile index: "
                    + staticTileIndex + " (there are only ["
                    + this.numberOfTiles + "] tiles available.");

        }
        this.animatedTiles.add(new Integer(staticTileIndex));
        return -1 * (this.animatedTiles.size() - 1);
    }

    public void setAnimatedTile(int animatedTileIndex, int staticTileIndex) {
        if (staticTileIndex >= this.numberOfTiles) {

        }
        int animatedIndex = (-1 * animatedTileIndex) - 1;
        this.animatedTiles.set(animatedIndex, new Integer(staticTileIndex));
    }

    public int getAnimatedTile(int animatedTileIndex) {
        int animatedIndex = (-1 * animatedTileIndex) - 1;
        Integer animatedTile = (Integer) this.animatedTiles.get(animatedIndex);
        return animatedTile.intValue();
    }

    public void setCell(int col, int row, int tileIndex) {
        if (tileIndex >= this.numberOfTiles) {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid static tile index: "
                    + tileIndex + " (there are only [" + this.numberOfTiles
                    + "] tiles available.");

        }
        this.grid[col][row] = tileIndex;
    }

    public int getCell(int col, int row) {
        return this.grid[col][row];
    }

    public boolean checkTileCollision(Sprite sp, int dir, int speed) {
        int curRow, curCollumn;

        int leftTile = 0, rightTile = 0, upTile = 0, downTile = 0;

        curRow = sp.getY() / cellHeight;
        curCollumn = sp.getX() / cellWidth;

        leftTile = grid[curCollumn - 1][curRow];
        rightTile = grid[curCollumn + 1][curRow];
        upTile = grid[curCollumn][curRow - 1];
        downTile = grid[curCollumn][curRow + 1];

        if (dir == DIR_RIGHT
                && (sp.getX() + sp.getWidth() + speed) <= (curCollumn + 1)
                        * cellWidth)
            return false;
        else if (dir == DIR_RIGHT
                && ((sp.getX() + sp.getWidth() + speed)) > (curCollumn + 1)
                        * cellWidth && rightTile != 1)
            return true;
        else if (dir == DIR_LEFT
                && (sp.getX() - speed) >= (curCollumn) * cellWidth)
            return false;
        else if (dir == DIR_LEFT
                && (sp.getX() - speed) < (curCollumn) * cellWidth
                && leftTile != 1)
            return true;
        else if (dir == DIR_UP && (sp.getY() - speed) >= (curRow) * cellHeight)
            return false;
        else if (dir == DIR_UP && (sp.getY() - speed) < (curRow) * cellHeight
                && upTile != 1)
            return true;
        else if (dir == DIR_DOWN
                && (sp.getY() + sp.getHeight() + speed) <= (curRow + 1)
                        * cellHeight)
            return false;
        else if (dir == DIR_DOWN
                && (sp.getY() + sp.getHeight() + speed) > (curRow + 1)
                        * cellHeight && downTile != 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void fillCells(int col, int row, int numCols, int numRows,
            int tileIndex) {
        if (tileIndex >= this.numberOfTiles) {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid static tile index: "
                    + tileIndex + " (there are only [" + this.numberOfTiles
                    + "] tiles available.");

        }
        int endCols = col + numCols;
        int endRows = row + numRows;
        for (int i = col; i < endCols; i++) {
            for (int j = row; j < endRows; j++) {
                this.grid[i][j] = tileIndex;
            }
        }
    }

    public final int getCellWidth() {
        return this.cellWidth;
    }

    public final int getCellHeight() {
        return this.cellHeight;
    }

    public final int getColumns() {
        return this.gridColumns;
    }

    public final int getRows() {
        return this.gridRows;
    }

    public final void paint(Graphics g) {

        for (int i = 0; i < this.gridRows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.gridColumns; j++) {
                Bitmap bmp = tileArray[grid[j][i]];
                g.drawImage(bmp, j * cellWidth, i * cellHeight);
            }
        }
    }

    public final void paint(Canvas c) {

        for (int i = 0; i < this.gridRows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.gridColumns; j++) {
                Bitmap bmp = tileArray[grid[j][i]];
                c.drawBitmap(bmp, j * cellWidth, i * cellHeight, null);
                // g.drawImage(bmp, j*cellWidth,i*cellHeight);
            }
        }

    }
}
```